# Передача данных по нажатию кнопки ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

В общем, я не очень силен в HTML. Я столкнулся с большой проблемой, а именно обработка данных.
За счет базовых знаний в HTML и C#(был использован движок Razor) я создал типичную форму с кучей кнопок radio и обычным button. Представим, что это входное тестирование. Группы radio названы именами qwestion1, qwestion2, qwestion3 и так далее...
В конце есть кнопочка. Сейчас пока она просто посылает пользователя на другую страницу. Прошу объяснить, как создать событие нажатия кнопки и считывание данных с radio. Или переформулирую вопрос - как создать обработку данных с формы и как сделать так, чтобы код запустился после нажатия кнопки?

```html
@{
StreamReadersr = new StreamReader(fileadress);
int count=0;
}
<form>
  @while(sr.ReadLine()!="########"){
  count++;
  string names="qwestion"+count;
   <p>
   <input type="radio" name=@names value="1"> @sr.ReadLine()<Br>
   <input type="radio" name=@names value="2">  @sr.ReadLine()<Br>
   <input type="radio" name=@names value="3">  @sr.ReadLine()
   </p>
   
  }
</form>
```

Comment: Вы здорово объясняете про Ваш html. Однако, еще лучше было бы включить этот html в вопрос. Рекомендую переименовать кнопки в "question...".

Comment: Я добавил код HTML, хранящийся в About.aspx.

Comment: Для отправки формы нужно делать submit формы. Нужно либо добавить кнопку submit, либо делать forms[0].submit(); по событию галочки.

Comment: у вас у form не указан action, куда вы отправите форму? вместо `<form>` используйте  `@using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller")) { //code }`